# GCC false positive warning on strncpy usage?

Tags: c++, c, g++, gcc-warning

Yet another question regarding strncpy warning.

Here's the code:

```
#include <cstring>

extern char g_dest[16];
extern char g_src[16];

char* mycopy()
{
    char * x = strncpy ( g_dest, g_src, sizeof ( g_dest ) - 1 );
    return x;
}
```

Compile it with `g++` version 8.3:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -c strncpy-warning2.cxx
strncpy-warning2.cxx: In function ‘char* mycopy()’:
strncpy-warning2.cxx:8:24: error: ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’ output may be truncated copying 15 bytes from a string of length 15 [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
     char * x = strncpy ( g_dest, g_src, sizeof ( g_dest ) - 1 );
                ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The warning can be worked around by either:

1. making the g_src shorter than g_dest:

```
$ cat strncpy-warning2.cxx
#include <cstring>

extern char g_dest[16];
extern char g_src[15];

char* mycopy()
{
    char * x = strncpy ( g_dest, g_src, sizeof ( g_dest ) - 1 );
    return x;
}
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -c strncpy-warning2.cxx
$
```

2. Or explicitly adding a NUL terminator at the end of `g_dest`:

```
$ cat strncpy-warning2.cxx
#include <cstring>

extern char g_dest[16];
extern char g_src[16];

char* mycopy()
{
    char * x = strncpy ( g_dest, g_src, sizeof ( g_dest ) - 1 );
    g_dest[ sizeof( g_dest ) - 1 ] = '\0';
    return x;
}
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -c strncpy-warning2.cxx
$
```

3. Or if I make the g_src a pointer instead of an array:

```
$ cat strncpy-warning2.cxx
#include <cstring>

extern char g_dest[16];
extern char* g_src2;

char* mycopy()
{
    char * x = strncpy ( g_dest, g_src2, sizeof ( g_dest ) - 1 );
    return x;
}
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -c strncpy-warning2.cxx
$
```

I understand that GCC is trying to warn against potential bugs on strncpy usage, however, I don't understand why we cannot do `strncpy` on 2 arrays of the same size? And why the warning message is saying `the output maybe truncated` ? ( i.e. I cannot find an example that the `output` can possibly be `truncated` unless GCC assumes `g_src` may not necessarily a valid NUL-terminated c-string. )

By googling, I see a similar case reported in GCC bugzilla: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87028, however, I'm not sure if that is the same case since that is marked as FIXED in the end but apparently my issue is still there in GCC 10.2.

Thank you!

Comment: `strncpy()`, despite its name, **was not** designed to work with strings... `char dst[4], src[4] = "foo"; strncpy(dst, src, 3);` will leave `dst[3]` with whatever random garbage it started with, ie `dst` is not a string.

Comment: Thanks pmg. By reading the man page of strncpy again, I understand what you mean: " Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.". And that's why if I explicitly add the NUL at the end, the warning is gone?

Comment: @LiuWei — yes.  The assignment after the `strncpy()` ensures that the result is a string.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Leffler, it looks like whenever strncpy usage triggers a warning, I should really be using memcpy at least for most of my use cases. ( and that is better for readability and maintainability as well IMHO )

Comment: Beginners think that `strncpy` is a "safe" version of `strcpy`, but it's not, unless "safe" means something completely unintuitive. It's tricky to use, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (most efficient, simplest, easiest to understand for both success and error cases) is to use memcpy when your source and destination are the same fairly small size.  GCC won't warn you about that.

If you simply want GCC to not complain about your strncpy() call even if it is unsafe, you can enclose it in parentheses like this:

```
char * x = (strncpy ( g_dest, g_src, sizeof ( g_dest ) - 1 ));
```

GCC understands this to mean "I know what I'm doing, don't try to save me from myself."

Comment: Thanks John for both tips! Looks like `memcpy` is mostly, if not 100%, the better choice at least for my use cases.

Comment: @LiuWei You're welcome.  You can "accept" an answer by clicking the checkmark on the left if it solved your problem.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I tried to accept @pmg's comment as the answer but looks like that's not possible. So I accept this one instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

The length passed to `strncpy` is the maximum number of bytes to copy, including a possible null terminator, not the “string length” that excludes the null terminator. Use `sizeof g_dest`, not `sizeof ( g_dest ) - 1`.

If `g_src` contains a string of 15 non-null characters and a null terminator, then `strncpy(g_dest, g_src, sizeof g_dest - 1);` will not copy it; it will copy only 15 characters and not copy the null terminator. Nor will it append a null terminator that is not already present and copied within the length (although it will append nulls up to the given length).

This is what the compiler is warning you about. `strncpy` should be passed the full length of the buffer, not the “string length.”

Comment: Thanks Eric. But I cannot pass the size of the destination as well, as that will results another warning from GCC as you can see from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915714/why-flto-silent-gccs-warning-stringop-truncation

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, I would rather use `strcpy()`. I tried to run `strncpy()` multiple times on other projects and I think that it is protected by the compiler due to cases when you create a string by for-loop without the `'\0'` operator. Maybe I am wrong but this reason was sufficient enough for me at that time.